# numpy where for array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The following code gets me `array([1, 1, 2])`, which is expected.

```
condition = [True, True, False]
array1 = [1, 1, 1]
array2 = [2, 2, 2]
print np.where(condition, array1, array2)
```

However, if my array1/2 contains themselves lists, them I get an error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (256,) (256,3) (256,3)`

```
array1=np.random.uniform(size=(256,3))
array2=np.random.uniform(size=(256,3))
np.where([random.random()>0.5 for x in range(256)],array1, array2)
```

How should I write the np.where to get an array that gets random elements from array1 or array2 (whole elements, it should preserve the whole array1[0] for example).

--- Update

If I use the following, as suggested on the comments/answers

```
np.where([np.random.uniform(size=(256,3))>0.5 for x in range(256)],array1, array2)
```

or

```
np.where([np.random.uniform(size=(256,1))>0.5 for x in range(256)],array1, array2)
```

... in both cases, the resulting matrix have a shape of (256,256,3), but I need the matrix to be the shape of (256,3)

The non-pythonic way of doing what I am trying to achieve is the following:

```
def mix_arrays(array1, array2):
    mix=[]
    for x in range(np.shape(array1)[0]):
        if random.random() > 0.5:
            mix.append(array1[x])
        else:
            mix.append(array2[x])
   return mix
```

Comment: Do you understand `broadcasting`?  The condition, `[random.random()>0.5 for x in range(256)]` needs to be (256,1) or (256,3) shaped to work with the other arrays.  `np.random.uniform(size=(256,1))>-.5` should work.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. See updated question

Comment: Play with this code outside of the `where` expression.  What does `np.random(..., size(256,1),...)` produce?  What happens when you embed it is in that `range(256)` comprehension?  Do you need that?  Test small pieces of the code and check the shape. Then build up to larger pieces, testing as you go along.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.random.uniform(size=(256,1))>-.5
```

or

```
np.random.uniform(size=(256,3))>-.5
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23105512)